# Groups $\pi$ with $K(\pi, 1)$ a finite CW-complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, open-problem

For what (say, finitely generated) groups $\pi$ is $K(\pi, 1)$ a finite CW-complex? Such a group must necessarily be torsion-free, since otherwise $H^*K(\pi, 1) = H^* \pi$ would be nontrivial in arbitrarily high dimensions. In the opposite direction, any non-positively curved manifold $X^n$ has $\exp:T_* X\to X$ a covering map by the Cartan-Hadamard theorem, and so $G = \pi_1 X$ works for reasonable such $X$. I've run across a couple of similar partial or ad-hoc results, but I think the general question is still unresolved. So, what's the current state of the question, and what are some neat partial results?

Comment: For the manifold case, Wall conjectured that $\pi$ is the fundamental group of a closed oriented $n$-manifold if and only if $\pi$ is a finitely presented $n$-dimensional Poincare duality group (usually written a $\text{PD}(n)$-group). I don't think it's known if you need to make further restrictions on this. There's a survey by Davis [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/pdgroup.pdf). (I haven't read it, but Davis's exposition is usually very clear.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For a reference for the following two definitions, see, for example, [this paper](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/scan/1979.0036.pdf).)

A group $G$ is said to be of *type FL* if $BG$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex, which is apparently equivalent to the condition that $\mathbb{Z}$ admits a finite free resolution as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module. A group $G$ is said to be of *type FP* if $BG$ is a homotopy retract of a finite CW complex (the standard term for this is "finitely dominated"), which is apparently equivalent to the condition that $\mathbb{Z}$ admits a finite projective resolution as a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module.

In general, if a space is a homotopy retract of a finite CW complex, then there is a further obstruction to it being homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex called [Wall's finiteness obstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall%27s_finiteness_obstruction). It's an open problem to determine whether this obstruction ever vanishes for classifying spaces $BG$, hence whether FP and FL are equivalent conditions on a group or not.

FP is a stronger version of the condition that $G$ is finitely presented (since it also implies that $G$ is torsion-free). It's probably hopeless to classify all such groups, in the same way that it's hopeless to classify all finitely presented groups, but you can at least ask for necessary and sufficient conditions, and probably if you search using these keywords you can find them in the literature.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think types FP and FL are what I was looking for: a translation of the topological condition of $\pi_1(G, 1)$ being finite into a purely algebraic (at least, modulo constructing the complex in Wall's finiteness obstruction) condition on $G$.

Comment: Your apparently equivalent statements were proved by Wall. The hard direction is that a free/periodic resolution means that $K(G,1)$ can be a finite CW complex. I have not checked but am fairly sure that a proof can be found in Wall's "Finiteness conditions for CW complexes, II", but using slightly different language.